# Ring floodlight camera won't connect to wifi

Tags: light-fixture, outdoor, wifi

I purchased four of the Ring Floodlight Cam Wired Plus to install around my house. I got the new electrical wiring installed to one of the floodlights and it powers on just fine. Going through the [regular installation instructions](https://support.ring.com/hc/en-us/articles/360061193531-Setting-Up-Floodlight-Cam-Wired-Plus-Security-Camera-in-the-Ring-App-), I get to the point where the lights try to connect to my wifi, but they fail.

Sometimes the light at the bottom of the camera is blue when it fails and sometimes it's green when retrying to make the connection. I've doublechecked the password and I've moved the router closer to the lights, since it says that there's interference, the signal is too weak, or that the wifi is too far away. The wifi router is now about 15-20 ft away and I can't get it any closer unless I have it hanging out the window and sitting on my roof. Checking the wifi on my phone shows there's plenty of signal strength, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Since I already have multiples of this light, I've replaced the floodlight in case the one just had a bad wireless device. I'm still getting the same problem with the 2nd light. I've also tried turning the router off and on again, as well as pressing the reset button on the floodlight's camera, but I keep getting the same green or blue lights from the camera.

What can I do to get the floodlight to get onto my wifi and finish the setup?

Comment: Glad to see you got this working, but this probably should be posted in SuperUser.com or [iot.se], not [diy.se].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic.

Comment: @FreeMan, I posted this where I think people are more likely going to be looking for this solution, which would be while doing home improvement, rather than setting up a computer or network. It is a networking problem, but it's specific to a device that's used for doing home improvements. I can definitely see this being useful on IoT, but your average home owner isn't likely going to be looking at that site. Just because it's on topic for one site, it isn't automatically off topic on another. I would think home automation would be covered under major appliances, as stated in the Tour.

Comment: Reasonable points. We'll see what the community thinks. I'm not going to be offended if nobody else agrees with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up calling the customer support number and going through the normal routine of turning stuff off and on again, but this didn't work. The support tech also had me install Ring on a second mobile device and try the setup that way, but got the same results with a blue or green light and the lights not connecting to the wifi.

I was eventually transferred to the engineering support and they had some more advanced information to work with.

It turns out that my NetGear wireless cable modem has a problem with the firmware installed on these lights, which happens to be fixed in later releases of the floodlight firmware. Evidently other brands and models of wifi devices have this same issue, too.

The way to get around this is to get internet through another device, either through a Ring Chime, another WAP, or other hotspot device.

I ended up turning on the hotspot feature from my cell phone and having the 2nd mobile device go through the wifi setup again to point the floodlight to use the hotspot, instead of my regular wifi, to connect to the internet. This was successful and the floodlight started to download the new firmware automatically. I left it connected this way until the firmware setup was complete, which took a few minutes. Once done downloading, the floodlights restarted a couple of times and the app said the setup was complete. After going through the rest of the steps to get back to the "home" screen, I could see video through the camera on my phone.

Knowing that everything was working correctly, I went into the settings for that floodlight camera to change the wifi to make it connect directly to my router. I had to tap the reset button on the floodlight to get it back into setup mode to reset the wifi connection. It was successful and I was able to see video through the app even after I disabled the hotspot on my phone.

Comment: Thanks for posting the final resolution.  I have worked with a lot of Ring installations and never heard of this problem.  Also never ran across the Netgear Cable modem.

Comment: @Programmer66, this seems to be a problem with just small handful of modems. When the engineer asked what modem I had, I couldn't remember the model, but after we talked and got it working, he was able to tell me a single model of Netgear cable modem and that sounded familiar. That's probably why it's a problem, since it's likely an edge case they didn't know about until after the lights were released. Also, I spent over 90 min trying to get this thing to work last night and don't want others to have to go through the same frustrations. Or at lease be able to search for a solution.